# Driving mini stepper motors from raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian

The questions is two fold:

1. What is the smallest stepper motor available that can be easily integrated with a raspberry pi?
2. Are there any tutorials/modules already available that I can use off the shelf?

Answer (score 1):

The [28BYJ-48](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/300948492482) is a popular choice.  If you get one make sure it is the 5V model and includes the driver board.

It doesn't have a great deal of torque and isn't very fast but it's a great introductory stepper.

You don't need anything else apart from the Pi and some jumper wire.

Here's a [video](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/misc/sonar/sonar3.mp4) of mine in action being controlled by the Pi.

There will be plenty of tutorials on the www.  Just google the model.  The code I used for the video is sonar_scan_2.py in http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/misc/sonar/

Comment: Thanks Joan. I was hoping to get something much smaller than this. I have to fit two such motors in tight space. I don't need a lot of torque, power or velocity.

Comment: I'm sure you can get smaller ones but that is outside my experience.  Hopefully someone else will know of some.  How small?  Have you any dimensions in mind?  If so you could edit your question to include them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a super small stepper-motor from old disc drives, it is bi-poled/bipolar ? so you will need a dual H-Bridge but is should not be a problem. The motor is 11mm in diameter gates not included.

As about running it, just go with any bipoled stepper totural.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=55580

Comment: I am assuming that with the change in size, there would be a change in the length of the pulse too. Is there a specific IC I should use with this stepper motor from the disc drive?

Comment: No the pulse is the same, i'm actually using the "L298N H-bridge Board - $3 from ebay" described in the guide. Spare your self some frustration and remember to connect ground to the controller.

Comment: There is an abundance of small steppers: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/mini-stepper-motor

Comment: Here is a more suitable driver for small motors. http://www.ebay.com/itm/L9110S-Dual-DC-motor-Driver-Controller-Board-H-bridge-Stepper-Motor-for-Arduino-/281489086003?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item418a0e9633